# Подключение js к вордпресс

Tags: javascript, wordpress

есть такой скрипт **JS**:

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('box-activ');
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0));
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.box-activ {
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p>какой-то текст</p>
</div>
<p class="open">Открыть</p>
```

Здесь реализовано раскрывающееся меню по кнопке ОТКРЫТЬ
Как\куда это засунуть в вордпресс? Какие плагины помогут мне в этом(желательно бесплатные)?
Заранее спасибо!)

Пробовал бесплатные плагины - не получалось. В файлы вордпресс не залазил, так как не нашел подробной инструкции

Comment: [Introduction to Plugin Development](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro), [написание плагина](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), [ещё куча всего](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+create+custom+plugin)...

Comment: Тебе надо освоить правильную работу с ВП, а ты сейчас пытаешься накостылить.

Answer (score 0):

В `functions.php` добавь:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'название|id скажем так твоего скрипта|произвольное поле',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'путь/до/твоего/скрипта',
        ['jquery'], // зависимости, в данном случае подключать его не обязательно так как wordpress использует его в своем ядре
        null, // версия, произвольное поле
        true // подключит скрипт в подвале
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts');
```

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` указывает на текущую тему `wp-content/themes/your_theme`. Аналогично подключишь стили функцией `wp_enqueue_style`. [Читай это](https://wp-kama.ru/)